# getting error while running python script

Tags: python, jenkins, devops

I am trying to run python script(below script) with parameters from jenkins file. When I am triggering  the job getting error "can't open file '/Users/--/---/--/---/--/Update.py ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Can anyone help ?

```
  def overrideJson = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "python3 /Users/anuj/---/--/---/--/Update.py input1  input2 ")
```

Comment: Well, clearly there is no such file.

Comment: Does the path that you provided ("/Users/anuj/---/--/---/--/Update.py") look like this in the actual script or are you just substituting directories with dashes in the question for privacy reasons?

Comment: the error says that : the file in the path you provided is not exist. Maybe your command in to that path is wrong

Comment: The exact path is /Users/ajangid/IdeaProjects/job/jenkinsfiles/Update.py . File is present in the local in the same path but when I am running it from the Jenkins UI I am getting this error.

Comment: use double // instead of single